# magento 2 How to add a div in main tag with custom phtml template in custom module

Tags: layout, magento-2.1.7, layout-update, page-layouts

I would like to add a div inside `<main id="maincontent" class="page-main">` from my custom module please look at screen shoot:

[image]

Can you see a `class="MYCUSTOMBLOCKHERE"` in the image I need to add this div.

Any help I Appreciate. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok  I've manage to ad like this But...

```
    <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
        <container name="custom.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-view" after="page.title.wrapper">
            <block class="company\module\Block\entity" name="customView" template="company_module::custom.phtml" />
        </container>
    </referenceContainer>
```

But it adds after `page messages` not before.

Answer (score 2):

```
<referenceContainer name="columns.top">
    <container name="custom.view.container" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="custom-view" before="page.messages">
        <block class="company\module\Block\entity" name="customView" template="company_module::custom.phtml" />
    </container>
</referenceContainer>
```

Flush cache and clear cache and check it.

you can find all block name into

> vendor\magento\module-theme\view\frontend\layout\default.xml

Comment: @Juliano Vargas is that works?

Comment: Great! thanks.  actually the correct name was **page.main.title** Do you know where I can find all this names like a list of it?

Comment: added :) that file

Comment: perfect answer!!! +1 made my day :)

Answer (score 1):

Add `<move>` tag to make it before page messgae.

```
<move element="custom.view.container" destination="columns.top" before="page.messages" />
```

Comment: Thanks this work too ! is there a list of this names tha one can refer to?